# Web app for counting votes on items

Tags: web-apps, voting

I was wondering if there exists any pre-built webpage systems/web apps for keeping track of votes on items, where users can submit new items to the list in addition to voting on them. What I want is basically a list of items, three vote options for each item, and the ability for the users to submit new items that will be approved by me and then added. I would also like to have captchas to prevent spam. An example would look something like this:

```
Item Name || Yes | No | Maybe|
Item 1    ||  87 | 3  |   9  |
Item 2    ||   3 | 2  |   4  |
Item 3    ||  59 | 43 | 200  |

Add new item.
__________________
|________________|   [Add]
```

The items will be permanent and seldomly removed. I think voting systems for webpages were more popular 10 years ago, so all I've found so far is from around that time. I will obviously not be using any if them since they are quite nasty. If nothing such exist then I will probably have to write it myself, but why reinvent the wheel and all that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might have something is WordPress with some type of plugin or creating it in SharePoint.

Comment: Can't any of those survey/poll websites do what you want? There's a lot of them.

Comment: @Jan Doggen Could you recommend one such a poll website? It is not clear for me what to search. I am working on a  voting system too.

Answer (score 2):

You can create such voting system with Google Drive in about 10 seconds. Click `Create` > `Form`. Then as `Question Type` select either `Multiple choice` or `Checkboxes` - whichever you prefer, and then click `Add "Other"` near the last option.